# how to use this function Map.getValue( thisRef: Any?, property: KProperty<*>)

Tags: function, kotlin

I see [this function on kotlinlang.org](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.collections/get-value.html), but i don't know how to use it.

```
operator fun <V, V1 : V> Map<in String, V>.getValue(
    thisRef: Any?,
    property: KProperty<*>
): V1
```

For example, I have this map: `val map = mapOf("one" to 1)`. How do you get 1 with this getValue function?

UPDATE:

Is there any way that you can get it to work with `val anotherMap = mapOf(1 to 1)`. Now the key is an `Int`. I've changed Map to Map<in `Int`, V>, but it won't work.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The [`getValue`](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.collections/get-value.html) operator function is declared on `Map`, so that `Map` can be used as a [property delegate](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/delegated-properties.html).

Note that the first parameter `thisRef` is ignored by the implementation. It is only included so that the function signature matches the signature required for a property delegate.

You will not normally call this function directly yourself. A call to `getValue` would be generated automatically when you use a `Map` as a property delegate, as part of the implementation of the property's setter.

What it does is rather straightforward - it accesses the map using the property name as key. See the code [here](https://github.com/JetBrains/kotlin/blob/80cce1dc5280eb9135390270c8644a7b8d198071/libraries/stdlib/src/kotlin/collections/MapAccessors.kt#L22).

Here is an example usage:

```
class User(val map: Map<String, Any?>) {
    val name: String by map
    val age: Int     by map
}

fun main() {
    val user = User(mapOf(
        "name" to "Sweeper", "age" to 42
    ))
    println(user.name) // prints Sweeper
}
```

In the setter for `name`, for example, the generated call to `getValue` would look something like:

```
map.getValue(this, this::name)
```

See also the "[storing properties in a map](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/delegated-properties.html#storing-properties-in-a-map)" section.

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned in [Indexed access operator﻿](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/operator-overloading.html#indexed-access-operator) you can just call

```kotlin
val value = map["one"]
```

to read the value `1`. But this doesn't call your special `getValue` function. You missed the function body to see what `getValue` it does. Here is an example for calling your method:

```kotlin
operator fun <V, V1 : V> Map<in String, V>.getValue(
    thisRef: Any?,
    property: KProperty<*>
): V1  = this[property.name] as V1

val map = mapOf("one" to 1)

data class Pojo(val one: String)

val pojo = Pojo("one")
val valueByProp : Int = map.getValue(map, Pojo::one)
```

Comment: Didn't get it, that it is part of the Kotlin Standard lib. Thought it was a sample code of a programming task.

Comment: Excellent. Just what I wanted to know.

Answer (score -1):

The documentation explains how to retrieve values data from `Map`s.

https://kotlinlang.org/docs/map-operations.html#retrieve-keys-and-values

> For retrieving a value from a map, you must provide its key as an argument of the [`get()`](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.collections/-map/get.html) function. The shorthand `[key]` syntax is also supported. If the given key is not found, it returns null. There is also the function [`getValue()`](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.collections/get-value.html) which has slightly different behavior: it throws an exception if the key is not found in the map.

```kotlin
val numbersMap = mapOf("one" to 1, "two" to 2, "three" to 3)
println(numbersMap.get("one"))
println(numbersMap["one"])
println(numbersMap.getOrDefault("four", 10))
println(numbersMap["five"])       // null
//numbersMap.getValue("six")      // exception!
```

Typically `getValue()` is used when using a `Map` [with a default](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.collections/with-default.html). See https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/KT-11851